# Can somebody check out this plsql function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this function that always returns a too many rows error, and therefore have to modify it to bulk collect into a nested table. However i seem to be unable to achieve this. It is supposed to receive a product name in the function call, and return the payment methods (metoda_de_plata) used to order that product. I will post the original version of the function so as for anybody to be able to see what the original variables are so that they can freely modify them, rather than be confused by the changed variables which likely are not correct.
Here are the tables used in this code:

```
  CREATE TABLE "METODA_PLATA" 
   (    "ID_PLATA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NUME_METODA_PLATA" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID_PLATA"))
CREATE TABLE "COMANDA" 
   (    "ID_COMANDA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_CLIENT" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_LIVRARE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_PLATA" NUMBER(*,0), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID_COMANDA"))
  
   CREATE TABLE "COMANDA_PRODUS" 
   (    "ID_COMANDA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_PRODUS" NUMBER(6,0), 
     FOREIGN KEY ("ID_COMANDA")
      REFERENCES "COMANDA" ("ID_COMANDA") ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("ID_PRODUS")
      REFERENCES "PRODUS" ("ID_PRODUS") ENABLE)
```

Here is my code:

```
create or replace function subprogram_ex8
(v_nume_produs produs.nume_produs%type)
return varchar2 is
v_metoda_plata metoda_plata.nume_metoda_plata%type;
begin
SELECT nume_metoda_plata INTO v_metoda_plata
FROM metoda_plata mp JOIN comanda c on mp.id_plata = c.id_plata
             JOIN comanda_produs cp on cp.id_comanda = c.id_comanda
             JOIN produs p on p.id_produs = cp.id_produs
WHERE upper(p.nume_produs)=upper(v_nume_produs);

RETURN v_metoda_plata;

exception
when too_many_rows
then
return 'eroare too many rows';
when
no_data_found
then
return 'nu s-au gasit date';


END subprogram_ex8;
```

As for expected output, it would be the payment methods used for said product, listed in a table format

Comment: you nee to produce **one** varchar2 value not a bunch of rows of varchar2

Comment: how do you expect to do a select into from multiple rows?  You could use LISTAGG to aggregate the values in a delimited list if the size of the data is < 4K.   otherwise, you can also create a pipelined function. You need to edit your question also to show sample table data and the expected output.

Comment: It's unclear if you are expecting multiple values - you said it returns *the* payment method, but then you're looking at a bulk collect, which might suggest getting multiples is OK. So are you actually expecting one value and are asking why the code you posted doesn't give you that; or you're expecting multiples and can't convert to a bulk version - in which case you should show what you are doing and what errors you get? Either way we don't know anything about your tables or data, or what the caller of this function is expecting - can it handle a (maybe pipelined) nested table, or ref cursor?

Comment: i do in deed wish to select multiple items and print them thru dbms. i will update my question for it to be clear

Comment: What does "print them thru dbms" mean?  You need to show sample data and expected output.

Comment: sorry, i am meaning that i want to store the info into a variable, probably a nested table, and print that variable in dbms. i will  try to add more useful info in the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of unclear what you really want - a function (that returns *something*), or a procedure (that just displays what it found - that's based on what you commented, saying that you want to "print them thru dbms").

Here are two examples, see if it helps.

You posted tables' description but no sample data so I'll use simpler example - only one table, Scott's EMP. Suppose I want to display jobs from department 10.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> select distinct job from emp where deptno = 10;

JOB
---------
MANAGER
PRESIDENT
CLERK
```

Function that returns a collection; I don't have to create my own type as I'll use built-in one:

```
SQL> create or replace function subprogram_ex8
  2    (v_nume_produs in number)
  3    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  4  is
  5    l_retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  6  begin
  7    select distinct job
  8      bulk collect
  9      into l_retval
 10      from emp
 11      where deptno = v_nume_produs;
 12    return l_retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select * from table(subprogram_ex8(10));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MANAGER
PRESIDENT
CLERK
```

Similarly, a procedure that loops through all jobs and displays them on the screen:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure subprogram_ex8_proc
  2    (v_nume_produs in number)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select distinct job from emp
  6                  where deptno = v_nume_produs)
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.job);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    subprogram_ex8_proc(10);
  3  end;
  4  /
MANAGER
PRESIDENT
CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

That's it, more or less. Try to adjust it to your case.

---

**[EDIT, based on discussion via comments]**

If you want to display result of the function, you can't just concatenate it in `dbms_output.put_line` calls because it expects a string, while function returns a collection.

One option to do that is to use a loop:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select * from table(subprogram_ex8(10))) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line('Metoda de plata este: ' || cur_r.column_value);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
Metoda de plata este: MANAGER
Metoda de plata este: PRESIDENT
Metoda de plata este: CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a very informative comment. i will post in a further comment my attempt at adapting it to my code, tables etc. However i am facing an issue: i have to call the function by the name of the product, which you will see in the select statement, but my call does not work, and the compiler tells me "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||' ". Do you know how i could solve this?

Comment: ```
create or replace function subprogram_ex8
 (v_nume_produs produs.nume_produs%type)
    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  is
    l_retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  begin
    select nume_metoda_plata
      bulk collect
      into l_retval
       FROM metoda_plata mp JOIN comanda c on mp.id_plata = c.id_plata
       JOIN comanda_produs cp on cp.id_comanda = c.id_comanda
       JOIN produs p on p.id_produs = cp.id_produs

      WHERE upper(p.nume_produs)=upper(v_nume_produs);
    return l_retval;
  end;
  /
```

Comment: There's no double pipe sign (i.e. the concatenation operator)  in function you posted in your last comment so ... no, I have no idea what you're talking about, sorry. Perhaps you should also post the way you **called** that function - I suspect that piece of code raises the error.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding! this is my call: begin
dbms_output.put_line('Metoda de plata este: ' || subprogram_ex8('Ghiveci flori'));
end;

Comment: That's because you're trying to concatenate a collection, and that won't work. See edited answer which shows how you might be doing it.